# How to download the blob data into xlsx

Tags: node.js

I inserted the `.xlsx` file into the table as BOLB then, I don't know how to convert the fetching blob data into xlsx using node js.

```
getting_blob_excel: function(users, req, res) {
        try
        {
            var qry = "SELECT upload_path, content_type FROM app_versions_log WHERE id = "+req.body.v_log_id+";";
            consumerDBconnection.query(qry, function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                utilController.LogError('1', 'appversionsupdatesController', 'getexcelAssets', err);
            } else if (results.length > 0) {
                console.log("results",results);
                var file_path = results[0].upload_path;
                var result = [{
                    "filecontent":file_path,
                    "filename":"prem.test.xlsx"
                }];



                //res.header("content-type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                    res.status(200);
                    res.send(utilController.successresponse(result));
                //res.send(result+);
            } else {
                res.status(400);
                res.send("Invalid format");
            }
        });
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            utilController.LogError('22', 'appversionsupdatesController', 'getting_blob_excel', err);
            res.status(500);
            res.send(global.internalServerError);
        }
    }
```